# How to write a CRUD/admin interface for an external database in django?

Tags: database, django, crud

I got a SQL Server instance with a users database on it. I want to use Django to write a nice administration interface for a techincal support team. That SQL Server is not managed by Django. It's been around for a while and is used by the entire system regulary.

I really want to be able to reuse some of Django's functionality like the admin interface, generic views for models, authentication and so on.

I realize this is quite a general question, I'm looking for general directions and/or best practices for this situation.

Currently I've been creating wrapper modules around database access (via raw SQL), but I fear it will only become more complicated as I'll add more features to the interface (like authentication).

Comment: You are looking for [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs)

Comment: @danihp and I guess making my models unmanaged as well

Comment: I think that this link is a answer for your question. You are looking for general direction and best practices. Do you need some more specific to your data?

Comment: From some reason, I previously skipped over the "django with legacy databases" articles since it seemed strange to me that django will create models for ALL the tables in that database. Most of them are irrelevant to my project. It just seemed like overkill for my needs.

Comment: definitely an overkill